# I am looking for recomendation for tablet-like device for personalized software

Tags: android, tablet, windows, 4k

I need personalized software for myself and **I am looking for a dedicated tablet-like device** to run this software.

Software would be mostly [CRUD applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) for objects made mostly from text and rarely with images/sound, but also with some graphical visualisation of those data.

There are few requirements for device:

- need to be able take it with me **in pocket** - so I guess suitable is only **8-10 inches** (is that right?)
- budget is **around 250USD** (buying in Europe, but we can speak about US prices), **maximum is 350USD**
- software would be done in **.NET**, so it needs to be **able to install Windows or Android** (then I can use Xamarin), no need to be preinstalled, I can reinstall OS myself
- sometimes I would need some **more space to watch and play with my data** and I do not want to export-import it through the computer, so **I would like to plug such a device to 4k monitor directly** (miniDisplayPort / DisplayPort / HDMI)
- sometimes I would need to write some longer text there, so **I would like to be able to plug a normal keyboard** (USB? mini-USB? or somehow else)

Additionally:

- there could be potentially **lots of data** and I would prefer to have it **stored in RAM memory most of time**, eventually on some small local database - so I guess I would need big RAM device
- I do not want to have a wireless internet connection (I guess every device have nowadays, so my plan B is to just never log to any WiFi network or maybe open device and destroy a wireless adapter)

**Anyone is able to recommend me some specific device?**

Comment: You'll not find anything that small in your budget to run Windows, so I'd focus on making sure Xamarin works well for your use case. I'd consider an older user large screen phone with the SIM card removed, a steel plate glued to its back, to affix it to a leather rectangle which also holds a Bluetooth keyboard.